# Find last event before given time for each row

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have two tables.

**Searches:**

```
user | eventtime
a    | 25/02/19 00:00
a    | 25/02/19 00:03
a    | 25/02/19 00:05
b    | 25/02/19 00:00
b    | 25/02/19 00:04
b    | 25/02/19 00:07
```

**Detail_hits:**

```
user | eventtime
a    | 25/02/19 00:04
b    | 25/02/19 00:04
b    | 25/02/19 00:05
```

Now for each entry in detail hits, I want to map it with its search time, which is the last search on or before the detail hits time for that user.

So the output would be like

```
user | eventtime      | searchtime
a    | 25/02/19 00:04 | 25/02/19 00:03
b    | 25/02/19 00:04 | 25/02/19 00:04
b    | 25/02/19 00:05 | 25/02/19 00:04
```

So far, I've tried

```
select user, detail_hits.eventtime, 
max(searches.eventtime) over(partition by user)
from detail_hits
left join searches using(user)
```

But this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses a `left join` and aggregation:

```
select dh.user, dh.eventtime, max(s.eventtime) as searchtime
from detail_hits dh left join
     searches s
     on dh.user = s.user and s.eventtime < dh.eventtime
group by dh.user, dh.eventtime;
```